# MPMediaItemArtwork crashed in iOS9

Tags: ios, ios9

```
if (image) {
    MPMediaItemArtwork *media = [[[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] init] initWithImage:image];  //crashed in this line,iOS9.
}
```

Error info:

> ERROR:    258: CA_UISoundClientBase::StartPlaying: AddRunningClient failed (status = -66681).
>   NSScanner: nil string argument

Why `MPMediaItemArtwork` crashed in iOS9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced crashing with the MPMediaItemArtwork initialization on the IOS9.

Try to change your line of code to this one:

MPMediaItemArtwork *media = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:image];

Would be happy to know if it helped anyone

Comment: Thanks!  It works for me.  I don‘t know why I write like this `[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] init] initWithImage` . wrong init.   :D

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, your original line:

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *media = [[[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] init] initWithImage:image];  //crashed in this line,iOS9.
```

should have worked.The main reason for breaking alloc from init in Objective-C, is to be able to re-initialize an (already initialized) object, like you did.

So you can file a bug with Apple, reporting the crash. The object returned from  `[[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] init]` should support reinitializing with an image. At the very least - reinitialization should have returned `nil` (if failed).

However - given the state of things, a simpler, more traditional, and working way to do this would be simply to initialize with the image on the first place, right after `alloc`, like thus:

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *media = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:image];
```